# Обработчик событий не видит объекты с this

Tags: javascript, ооп, библиотеки

### Доброго времени суток

Сейчас я пишу класс и в нем есть метод, который создает слайдер. Внутри данного метода я создал два обработчика событий, но внутри обработчика событий не видны объекты с this.

**Сам класс**

```
class sliders{
    constructor(leftButton, rightButton, classImg){
        this.leftButton = leftButton;
        this.rightButton = rightButton;
        this.classImg = classImg;
    }
    createSlider(){
        this.sliderButtonLeft = document.getElementsByClassName(this.leftButton)[0];
        this.sliderButtonRight = document.getElementsByClassName(this.rightButton)[0];
        this.sliderArrayImg = [];
        for(this.counter = 1;  this.counter <= document.getElementsByClassName(this.classImg).length; this.counter++){
            this.sliderArrayImg[this.counter-1] = document.getElementsByClassName(this.classImg)[this.counter-1];
        }
        this.counter = 0;
        this.sliderButtonLeft.onclick = function(){
            this.sliderArrayImg[this.counter].style.display = "none";
            this.counter--;
            this.sliderArrayImg[this.counter].style.display = "block";
        }
        this.sliderButtonRight.onclick = function(){
            this.sliderArrayImg[this.counter].style.display = "none";
            this.counter++;
            this.sliderArrayImg[this.counter].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
};
```

Как сделать так, чтобы обработчик событий смог работать с объктами внутри класса?

Comment: Используйте стрелки для проброса this: `this.sliderButtonLeft.onclick = ()
 => {`, `this.sliderButtonRight.onclick = () => {`.

Comment: Попробую это применить)